# Редирект 301 с условием если страница отдает 404

Tags: .htaccess, битрикс, редирект

Подскажите пожалуйста как создать правило 301 редирект если страница отдает 404, то редиректит на родительский уровень.
Пример:
[www.mysite.ru/web_studio/blogs/650/](http://www.mysite.ru/web_studio/blogs/650/) если ответ 404 то редирект на уровень выше [www.mysite.ru/web_studio/blogs/](http://www.mysite.ru/web_studio/blogs/) если и тут 404 идет на уровень выше [www.mysite.ru/web_studio/](http://www.mysite.ru/web_studio/)

В заранее благодарю!

Answer (score 0):

Штатными настройками Битрикс такое не реализовать. Зависит от того, как у вас настроена страница 404.

В идеале должна быть настройка на файл 404.php. Если это так, тогда логику можно прописать внутри 404.php, но тут возможны два варианта

1. Если у вас настроен именно редирект на 404.php (т.е. в адресе прописывается /404.php, тогда в самом файле можно попробовать перехватывать REFFERER, у него отсекать ненужную часть и через Redirect() перенаправлять пользователя
2. Если настроена подстановка 404.php со сохранением адреса, тогда в файле парсить текущий адрес, выкидывать лишнее, и опять же через Redirect() перенаправлять

Если все же речь про какой-нибудь 404.html, прописанный в настройках сервера, то можно в нем через JS реализовать аналог того, что в п.1